# How to get the size of result generated using concat_ws?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am performing `groupBy` on COL1 and getting the concatenated list of COL2 using `concat_ws`. How can I get the count of values in that list? Here's my code:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = df.groupBy("COL1").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions
    .concat_ws(",",org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("COL2")).as("sample"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [size](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@size(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **size(e: Column): Column** Returns length of array or map.

---

The following example is in Scala and am leaving it to you to convert it to Java, but the general idea is exactly the same regardless of the programming language.

```
val input = spark.range(4)
  .withColumn("COL1", $"id" % 2)
  .select($"COL1", $"id" as "COL2")
scala> input.show
+----+----+
|COL1|COL2|
+----+----+
|   0|   0|
|   1|   1|
|   0|   2|
|   1|   3|
+----+----+

val s = input
  .groupBy("COL1")
  .agg(
    concat_ws(",", collect_list("COL2")) as "concat",
    size(collect_list("COL2")) as "size") // <-- size
scala> s.show
+----+------+----+
|COL1|concat|size|
+----+------+----+
|   0|   0,2|   2|
|   1|   1,3|   2|
+----+------+----+
```

---

In Java that'd be as follows. Thanks [Krishna Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5061863/krishna-prasad) for sharing the code with the SO/Spark community!

```
Dataset<Row> ds = df.groupBy("COL1").agg(
  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws(",",org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("‌​COL2")).as("sample")‌​, 
  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.size(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("COL2‌​")).as("size"));
```

Comment: Will there be a difference in calling `collect_list` twice vs creating an array by calling `collect_list` once and then using `withColumn` twice to call `size` and `concat_ws` on the array ?

Comment: A very interesting question that would stand on its own on StackOverflow. I don't know for sure, but would expect that Spark SQL does `collect_list` first before using it in two places. Highly recommend asking this question and see what the Spark community has to say on it.