# Spark Plan for collect_list

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is with reference [Jacek's answer to How to get the size of result generated using concat_ws?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506231/7224597)

The DSL query in the answer calls `collect_list` twice with `concat` and `size` separately.

```
input.groupBy($"col1").agg(
     concat_ws(",", collect_list($"COL2".cast("string"))) as "concat",
     size(collect_list($"COL2".cast("string"))) as "size"
)
```

With an`optimizedPlan` like :

```
Aggregate [COL1#9L], 
[COL1#9L,
concat_ws(,,(hiveudaffunction(HiveFunctionWrapper(GenericUDAFCollectList,GenericUDAFCollectList@470a4e26),cast(COL2#10L as string),false,0,0),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false)) AS concat#13,
size((hiveudaffunction(HiveFunctionWrapper(GenericUDAFCollectList,GenericUDAFCollectList@2602f45),cast(COL2#10L as string),false,0,0),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false)) AS size#14]
+- Project [(id#8L % 2) AS COL1#9L,id#8L AS COL2#10L]
   +- LogicalRDD [id#8L], MapPartitionsRDD[20] at range at <console>:25
```

How will it be different performance-wise, if I use `collect_list` only once and then `withColumn` API to generate the other two columns?

```
input
  .groupBy("COL1")
  .agg(collect_list($"COL2".cast("string")).as("list") )
  .withColumn("concat", concat_ws("," , $"list"))
  .withColumn("size", size($"list"))
  .drop("list")
```

Which has an `optimizedPlan` like :

```
Project [COL1#9L,
concat_ws(,,list#17) AS concat#18,
size(list#17) AS size#19]
+- Aggregate [COL1#9L], 
[COL1#9L,(hiveudaffunction(HiveFunctionWrapper(GenericUDAFCollectList,GenericUDAFCollectList@5cb88b6b),
   cast(COL2#10L as string),false,0,0),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false) AS list#17]
   +- Project [(id#8L % 2) AS COL1#9L,id#8L AS COL2#10L]
      +- LogicalRDD [id#8L], MapPartitionsRDD[20] at range at <console>:25
```

I see `collect_list` being called twice in the former example but just wanted to know if there are any significant differences apart from that. Using Spark 1.6.

Comment: I'm trying to see if my eyes are playing tricks on me. It has the same plan ?

Comment: @eliasah I have removed the package name and tried to indent it a little. See if it's a more readable now.

Comment: Ok now I see better what you are asking. Indeed that will perform extra aggregations.